# javafx combobox selectionmodel is not consistant

Tags: javafx, combobox

I am creating javafx application where I insert selected items of combobox which are also populated from database to another table of database but problem is that combobox's selection model is not working consistent some time it is giving item which are selected but some it sends null value to database

Code:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;

public class EntryFormController implements Initializable {

Connection connection = SqliteConnection.Connector();
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

ObservableList<String> cBoxList1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<String> cBoxList2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


@FXML
private ComboBox<String> TruckNo;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> exp1;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> exp2;

@FXML
private void addButton(ActionEvent e) {
    String query = "insert into entry (Truck,Expense)values(?,?),(?,?) ";

    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString
        (2,TruckNo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        preparedStatement.setString
        (3, exp1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        TruckNo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        preparedStatement.setString
        (9,exp2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

        preparedStatement.execute();

        TruckNo.setValue(null);
        TruckNo.valueProperty().set(null);
        exp1.setValue(null);
        exp1.valueProperty().set(null);
        exp2.setValue(null);
        exp2.valueProperty().set(null);

        preparedStatement.close();


    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    exp1.setItems(cBoxList1);
    exp1.setEditable(true);
    loadDatabaseDataCombo1();
    exp2.setItems(cBoxList2);
    exp2.setEditable(true);     
    TruckNo.setItems(trkList);
    TruckNo.setEditable(true);
    loadDatabaseDataCombo6();

    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(exp1.getEditor(), exp1.getItems());
    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(exp2.getEditor(), exp2.getItems());
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(TruckNo.getEditor(),TruckNo.getItems());

}

private void loadDatabaseDataCombo6() {
    String query = "select * from Truck";
    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            trkList.add(rs.getString("TruckNo"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}


private void loadDatabaseDataCombo2() {
    String query = "select * from Expense";
    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            cBoxList2.add(rs.getString("name"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void loadDatabaseDataCombo1() {
    String query = "select * from Expense";
    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            cBoxList1.add(rs.getString("name"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: that's a way too much code for a reasonable person to analyze. Please, try to prepare a shorter example instead. Here are guidelines: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: I have tried to make it short please help me now some time Combobox selection model is getting selected items but some time null value is inserted in database